# DX11 CreateTexture2D

Tags: directx, directx11

When i want to load texture i can either call
`CreateTexture2D` without passing pointer to texture content passing Default usage and call `UpdateSubResource`

or

`CreateTexture2D` with pointer to texture content passing Immutable or Default as usage.

In first case texture is uploaded to GPU, in seconds case it is also backed to RAM. IIRC it is a so called Managed Pool that help with device loss, but i have hand-made mechanism to handle device loss, i don't want DX to consume pretty big amount of RAM for nothing.

I would be easy to stick with 1st option, but if i call `UpdateSubResource` from BG thread it sometimes crashes (because it uses `ImmediateContext` that is used on render thread).

Is there any way to tell DX11 not to copy textures to RAM on `CreateTexture2D`?

Comment: There is no such thing as "lost device" in D3D11 (only a swapchain can be "lost"... or a device can be completely reset) and no managed pools, so... nothing? Any local copies you're detecting somehow is likely related to how the driver has to stage uploads in the DMA queue. The driver can also move memory back to the CPU when it deems fit based on GPU memory pressure (think of it like virtual swap space for your GPU).

Comment: Lost device = Device removed (switch of graphics cards or driver crash, and few more cases). It happens less often than in D3D9 but still happens.

I just want to avoid RAM-backing of my textures. I think that games like Far Cry or Crysis don't have second copy of the textures. Otherwise they would eat too much memory

Comment: Are you aware that in the second case you can free the memory after making the CreateTexture2D call?

Comment: If you mean that i can free RAM but leave texture in GPU memory - then no. This is exactly what i want to do!

Comment: @Grigory - exactly that, yes.  malloc a bunch of RAM, CreateTexture2D using the second case, free the RAM, the texture is still in GPU memory.